# Laravel 5.5: Route not catching/missing single parameter

Tags: php, parameters, routes, laravel-5.5

It appears the parameter is not passing, but after various edits no luck, and no way to strip it down anymore than this.

Error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: request.new-request] 
[URI: housing-request/{unit}]. 
(View: /vhosts/web.local/resources/views/requests/unit-1.blade.php)
```

Link/URL:

```
<a href="{{ route('request.new-request', ['unit' => 'single']) }}">
http://web.local/housing-request/single
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/housing-request/{unit}', 'RequestsController@showHousingUnit')->name('request.new-request');
```

Controller:

```
  public function showHousingUnit($unit)
  {

      if($unit == "single"){

         return view('requests.unit-1');

      } else if($unit == "double") {

        return view('requests.unit-2');

     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was on a route inside the view which was missing the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Just pass like this.

```
<a href="{{ route('request.new-request','single') }}">
http://web.local/housing-request/single </a>
```